# Run time Application Logging during spark execution

Tags: apache-spark

I have an application written for Spark using Scala language. My application code is kind of ready and the job runs for around 10-15 mins.

There is an additional requirement to provide status of the application execution when spark job is executing at run time. I know that spark runs in lazy way and it is not nice to retrieve data back to the driver program during spark execution. Typically, I would be interested in providing status at regular intervals.

Eg. if there 20 functional points configured in the spark application then I would like to provide status of each of these functional points as and when they are executed/ or steps are over during spark execution.

These incoming status of function points will then be taken to some custom User Interface to display the status of the job.

Can some one give me some pointers on how this can be achieved.

Comment: https://github.com/hammerlab/grafana-spark-dashboards

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do on this front that I can think of.

If your job contains multiple actions, you can write a script to poll for the expected output of those actions.  For example, imagine your script have 4 different **DataFrame** save calls.  You could have your status script poll **HDFS**/**S3** to see if the data has showed up in the expected output location yet.  Another example, I have used Spark to index to **ElasticSearch**, and I have written status logging to poll for how many records are in the index to print periodic progress.

Another thing I tried before is use **Accumulators** to try and keep rough track of progress and how much data has been written.  This works ok, but it is a little arbitrary when Spark updates the visible totals with information from the executors so I haven't found it to be too helpfully for this purpose generally.

The other approach you could do is poll Spark's status and metric APIs directly.  You will be able to pull all of the information backing the Spark UI into your code and do with it whatever you want.  It won't necessarily tell you exactly where you are in your driver code, but if you manually figure out how your driver maps to stages you could figure that out.  For reference, here are is the documentation on polling the status API:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api